# Should structure packing used to build libstdc++.a matter when using STL containers?

Tags: c++, stl

We're adding new functionality in C++ to a large legacy embedded application written in C, that uses a structure packing of 1 byte across the project (for historical reasons, that may or may not be valid now).

Using tool chain `arm-none-eabi-g++`, we ran into an issue in usage of `std::map` because `libstdc++.a` (which is pre-built by the tool vendor, with default packing of 4 bytes) had a different idea about what `struct _Rb_tree_node_base` (in `arm-none-eabi\include\c++\4.7.3\bits\stl_tree.h`) looked like, because of the

```
enum _Rb_tree_color { _S_red = false, _S_black = true };
```

data member in that structure is 1 byte wide in my program vs 4 bytes in the library.

I was a bit surprised to discover this to be a problem because I had assumed all of STL containers code would be pure headers (at least all the bits that I should be worried about). Basically a small piece of code for map implementation is built as part of the library (example `\arm-none-eabi\src\gcc\libstdc++-v3\src\c++98\tree.cc`).

My question is, regardless of what I should be doing differently regarding packing (the gory details of which I will not go into), is it correct behavior for an implementation detail such as `struct _Rb_tree_node_base`, that is not part of documented public interface of `std::map` to be causing me grief? Or is it not the responsibility of a library provider to ensure that implementation details don't leak out and cause problems to client code?

Comment: Neither the building of libraries nor a notion of "packing" are part of the language standard.

Comment: @Kerrek I was not implying that the standard is being violated, but rather this could be a library implementation issue. Perhaps not.

Comment: You've asked about "correct behaviour", so the question is, "correct" in what sense?

Comment: Ok when I said "correct", I meant in a general sense in terms of good object oriented design principles. In this case that would be a separation of interface from implementation. The internal red black tree being implementation whereas std::map<> being the interface. As such when I #include <map> and some public structure documented as part of std namespace breaks due to misalignment, then my question does not arise.

Comment: Anyways I accept the answer below because due to practical (non-technical) issues I cannot force all parts of the application (a monolith that includes the RTOS) to be 4 byte aligned.

Comment: Another way to look at it is that red black tree is not implementation but rather part of the interface in generic programming paradigm. However in that case I think the entire code for the instantiation of std::map<mykeytype,myvaltype> class should be compiled as part of my application (being in header or inline functions) rather than some arbitrary pieces being in the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're completely on your own there, unless your library vendor documents the behavior when you do what you just did (in which case feel free to file a bug report).

If you change compilation settings that affect the size of classes (or structs or whatever) for two compilation units that see the same header, you can't link them together - that would essentially be a violation of the ODR (One Definition Rule), i.e. you'd be linking code that have seen different definitions for the same object.

It's your responsibility to make sure this doesn't happen, i.e. not to mix objects compiled with different packing/padding options. Nothing in the standard guarantees anything regarding this.